# why configuration key "quarkus.servlet.context-path" is not working

Tags: quarkus

use quarkus framework online build tools to quickly set up a restful project.

then start the project, I found issue:

Unrecognized configuration key "quarkus.servlet.context-path" was provided.

don't know what reason for that.

```
 $ ./mvnw clean compile quarkus:dev
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO] 
[INFO] --------------------< com.xuanwugate:code-testing >---------------------
[INFO] Building code-testing 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT
[INFO] --------------------------------[ jar ]---------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) @ code-testing ---
[INFO] Deleting /Users/xiaods/Desktop/code-testing/target
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ code-testing ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 2 resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.8.1:compile (default-compile) @ code-testing ---
[INFO] Changes detected - recompiling the module!
[INFO] Compiling 1 source file to /Users/xiaods/Desktop/code-testing/target/classes
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- quarkus-maven-plugin:1.3.1.Final:dev (default-cli) @ code-testing ---
Listening for transport dt_socket at address: 5005
__  ____  __  _____   ___  __ ____  ______ 
 --/ __ \/ / / / _ | / _ \/ //_/ / / / __/ 
 -/ /_/ / /_/ / __ |/ , _/ ,< / /_/ /\ \   
--\___\_\____/_/ |_/_/|_/_/|_|\____/___/   
2020-03-29 23:38:52,287 WARN  [io.qua.config] (main) Unrecognized configuration key "quarkus.servlet.context-path" was provided; it will be ignored
2020-03-29 23:38:52,502 INFO  [io.quarkus] (main) code-testing 1.0.0-SNAPSHOT (powered by Quarkus 1.3.1.Final) started in 0.830s. Listening on: http://0.0.0.0:8080
2020-03-29 23:38:52,503 INFO  [io.quarkus] (main) Profile dev activated. Live Coding activated.
2020-03-29 23:38:52,503 INFO  [io.quarkus] (main) Installed features: [cdi, resteasy]
```

Comment: It is a warning that the configuration is specified, but not used by the software. Do you have the key configured in the application.properties file or the POM file properties?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do you have a dependency on `io.quarkus:quarkus-undertow`? If you only have `io.quarkus:quarkus-resteasy`, then JAX-RS is running directly on top of Vert.x, servlet is not present and the configuration key won't work. If you need servlet, add Undertow, but if you only need to configure the "root path", you can use the `quarkus.http.root-path` configuration property.